# tomcat to send SSL client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I am trying to do a https rest API call with a SSL certificate(PFX file) which have a password. I tested the connection from my desktop with SOAP UI and it is working fine.

I have a web application which is running on tomcat and I need my tomcat to send this certificate for all the http/https call which it will make.

I am not a tomcat person so i am stuck with this now.
I can find in online about how to set up a keystore & server.xml so that my web app can use Client Authentication against things connecting to it, not for when it needs to connect out to some other server(outgoing call).

my tomcat version is : 9.0.22

connector settings on my server.xml file

Comment: Tomcat is irrelevant; it handles _incoming_ connections only. That's why the config file is named server.xml, and the keystore in server.xml is used for_server_ auth, not client. _Any_ Java app, including a web app in Tomcat, can make outgoing connections, but what matters is what the app does or uses, not that it is in a tomcat environment. There are hundreds or thousands of ways for an app to make outgoing connections, and an answer covering all of them would take many years to write, so I won't. If you ask a more specific question, it might be answerable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the response, i also read this link looks like he also had the same issue but the solution didnt help me.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552345/tomcat-client-authentication-using-ssl