# How to restrict Tomcat access by IP in windows 10 firewall?

Tags: tomcat, windows-firewall

Now, anyone could access my tomcat via IP address. Therefore I would like to restrict it by allowing only specific IPs to access my tomcat in windows 10 firewall.

I tried to add the following inbound firewall rule, but still anyone could access my tomcat.

- Profile: All (Domain, Private, Public)
- Enabled: Yes
- Action: Allow the connection
- Override: No
- Program: Any
- Local Address: Any
- Remote Address: x.x.x.x (The allowed IPs)
- Protocol: TCP
- Local Port: 8080
- Remote Port: Any
- Authorized Users: Any
- Authorized Computers: Any
- Authorized Local Principals: Any
- Local User Owner: Any
- Application Package: Any

After some studying and testing, I suspect that one of the existing inbound firewall rule on javaw.exe take precedence over my tomcat firewall rule, which allow anyone to access my tomcat.

- Profile: Private
- Enabled: Yes
- Action: Allow the connection
- Override: No
- Program: javaw.exe
- Local Address: Any
- Remote Address: Any
- Protocol: TCP and UDP
- Local Port: Any
- Remote Port: Any
- Authorized Users: Any
- Authorized Computers: Any
- Authorized Local Principals: Any
- Local User Owner: Any
- Application Package: Any

Do I need to allow javaw.exe connection in firewall for running Tomcat? Are there any ways to enable both tomcat and javaw.exe firewall rules such that I still can restrict specific IPs to access my tomcat?

I knew that I could restrict access by setting RemoteAddrValve in tomcat server.xml, but still according to tomcat security consideration, it is better to set multiple lines of defense. Therefore I still would like to add a firewall rule in the network layer to restrict the tomcat connection. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have defaults tomcat rules who give access to everybody. Windows firewall apply rules in this order:

1. GPO **deny**
2. GPO allow
3. local rule **deny**
4. local rule allow
5. finaly global rule (deny by default)

Two way to handle that:

1. create a rule that deny everybody with exception for IP selected (very complex to do that, you need to calculate [0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255] substracted to [my ip range]
2. remove all the rules of your Windows Firewall and then make clean rules.

I prefer to remove all the rules of the Windows Firewall and then make clean rules.
For a Windows server, you will need 3389 (RDP), 445 if you use psexec and 80/443 for you http web app.
If your server is joingned to a domain, you can do that via GPO with a good OU management:

If you split your OU on a role based:

```
OU=AllComputers
    >GPO=Allow all TCP port inbound for my admin range IP
  OU=Workstations
  OU=Laptops
  OU=Servers
    OU=Web
      >GPO=Allow 80,443 TCP port inbound for ????
    OU=Database
      >GPO=Allow 1433 TCP port inbound for everybody
    OU=TerminalServer
      >GPO=Allow 3389 TCP port inbound for everybody
    OU=DNS
      >GPO=Allow 53 TCP port inbound for everybody
    OU=FileServer
      >GPO=Allow 445 TCP port inbound for everybody
```

You have another solution, use SSL and set a client certificate, so only users who have the certificate can connect to the webapp:

- [Tomcat Client Authentication using SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552345/tomcat-client-authentication-using-ssl)
- https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/